# how to move axes labels to near the arrows in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

below is my code that plots a function, and I need to move the "X" and "Y" labels into the first quadrant, to where they are conventionally placed near the corresponding arrows. how is this done?

```
import pylab as p
import numpy as n

from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid import axislines


def cubic(x) :
    return x**3 + 6*x


def set_axes():
    fig = p.figure(1)
    ax = axislines.SubplotZero(fig, 111)
    fig.add_subplot(ax)

    for direction in ['xzero', 'yzero']:
        ax.axis[direction].set_axisline_style('->', size=2)
        ax.axis[direction].set_visible(True)

    for direction in ['right', 'top', 'left', 'bottom']:
        ax.axis[direction].set_visible(False)

    ax.axis['xzero'].set_label('X')
    ax.axis['yzero'].set_label('Y')

    ax.axis['yzero'].major_ticklabels.set_axis_direction('right')
    ax.axis['yzero'].set_axislabel_direction('+')
    ax.axis['yzero'].label.set_rotation(-90)
    ax.axis['yzero'].label.set_va('center')


set_axes()

X = n.linspace(-15,15,100)
Y = cubic(X)

p.plot(X, Y)

p.xlim(-5.0, 5.0)
p.ylim(-15.0, 15.0)

p.xticks(n.linspace(-5, 5, 11, endpoint=True))
p.grid(True)

p.show()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally, to change an axis's (e.g. `ax.xaxis`) label position, you'd do `axis.label.set_position(xy)`.  Or you can just set one coordinate, e.g. 'ax.xaxis.set_x(1)`.

In your case, it would be:

```
ax['xzero'].label.set_x(1)
ax['yzero'].label.set_y(1)
```

However, `axislines` (and anything else in `axisartist` or `axes_grid`) is a somewhat outdated module (which is why `axes_grid1` exists).  It doesn't subclass things properly in some cases.  So, when we try to set the x and y positions of the labels, nothing changes!

---

A quick workaround would be to use `ax.annotate` to place labels at the ends of your arrows.  However, let's try making the plot a different way first (after which we'll wind up coming back to `annotate` anyway).

---

These days, you're better off using the new spines functionality to do what you're trying to accomplish.

Setting the x and y axes to be "zeroed" is as simple as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for spine in ['left', 'bottom']:
    ax.spines[spine].set_position('zero')

# Hide the other spines...  
for spine in ['right', 'top']:
    ax.spines[spine].set_color('none')

ax.axis([-4, 10, -4, 10])
ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

[image]

However, we still need the nice arrow decoration.  This is a bit more complex, but it's just two calls to annotate with the approriate arguments.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#-- Set axis spines at 0
for spine in ['left', 'bottom']:
    ax.spines[spine].set_position('zero')

# Hide the other spines...
for spine in ['right', 'top']:
    ax.spines[spine].set_color('none')

#-- Decorate the spins
arrow_length = 20 # In points

# X-axis arrow
ax.annotate('', xy=(1, 0), xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'), 
            xytext=(arrow_length, 0), textcoords='offset points',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<|-', fc='black'))

# Y-axis arrow
ax.annotate('', xy=(0, 1), xycoords=('data', 'axes fraction'), 
            xytext=(0, arrow_length), textcoords='offset points',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<|-', fc='black'))

#-- Plot
ax.axis([-4, 10, -4, 10])
ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

[image]

(The width of the arrow is controlled by the text size (or an optional parameter to the `arrowprops`), so specifying something like `size=16` to `annotate` will make the arrow a bit wider, if you'd like.)

---

At this point, it's easiest to just add the "X" and "Y" labels as a part of the annotation, though setting their positions would work as well.

If we just pass in a label as the first argument to annotate instead of an empty string (and change the alignment a bit) we'll get nice labels at the ends of the arrows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#-- Set axis spines at 0
for spine in ['left', 'bottom']:
    ax.spines[spine].set_position('zero')

# Hide the other spines...
for spine in ['right', 'top']:
    ax.spines[spine].set_color('none')

#-- Decorate the spins
arrow_length = 20 # In points

# X-axis arrow
ax.annotate('X', xy=(1, 0), xycoords=('axes fraction', 'data'), 
            xytext=(arrow_length, 0), textcoords='offset points',
            ha='left', va='center',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<|-', fc='black'))

# Y-axis arrow
ax.annotate('Y', xy=(0, 1), xycoords=('data', 'axes fraction'), 
            xytext=(0, arrow_length), textcoords='offset points',
            ha='center', va='bottom',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<|-', fc='black'))

#-- Plot
ax.axis([-4, 10, -4, 10])
ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

[image]

With a only a tiny bit more work (directly accessing the spine's transform), you can [generalize the use of annotate](https://gist.github.com/3845684) to work with any type of spine alignment (e.g. "dropped" spines, etc).

At any rate, hope that helps a bit.  You can also [get fancier with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694478/center-origin-in-matplotlib/4718438#4718438), if you'd like.

Comment: thanks! one problem with using annotations to draw arrows is that the arrows are thicker a little than the axes.