# How can I change plt.plot x axis from 0 to real value?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

HELLO. I'm now drawing line graph from years and number dictionary data.
When I tried to draw line graph by using matplotlib.pyplot, Its axis continuously is fixed 0.

For example, I want to draw graph from dictonary(
**year_counts=  {'2013':7, '2014':20, '2015':10, '2016':37, '2017':1}**).But Its axis started with 0 and increased by 1.
Even though I set the x limit,
plt.xlim(xmin=int(years[0])) *OR*
plt.axis([int(years[0]), int(years[-1]), 0, max(book_counts)])
It doesn't work.

How can I start x-axis with 2013?

This is the code that I used

```
year_counts=  {'2013':7, '2014':20, '2015':10, '2016':37, '2017':1}

years = sorted(year_counts)
book_counts = [year_counts[year] for year in years]
plt.plot(years, book_counts)
plt.xlim(xmin=int(years[0])) # didn't work
plt.axis([int(years[0]), int(years[-1]), 0, max(book_counts)]) # didn't work
plt.show()
```

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html#pylab-examples-example-code-spine-placement-demo-py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center origin in matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694478/center-origin-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib yaxis range display using absolute values rather than offset values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303728/matplotlib-yaxis-range-display-using-absolute-values-rather-than-offset-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your axis actually starts at 2013, which is `0 + 2.013e3` as seen in the picture.

In order to get rid of this offset, use

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```