# python plotting - strange axis formatting

Tags: python, matplotlib, formatting, axis, figure

By plotting with matplotlib sometimes I have this sort of axis format. The values are correct (checked debugging), the only problem is displaying.

[image: Example]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8.5))
plt.subplot(311)
plt.plot(t_p, L_p)
plt.title('Lift')
plt.xlabel('Time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Lift [N]')
plt.ylim(min(L_p), max(L_p))
plt.matplotlib.pyplot.tight_layout(pad=1.08, h_pad=None, w_pad=None,rect=None)
```

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: You can set the power limits, check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775040/matplotlib-axis-label-format

Comment: It looks pretty fine? How should it look like? Can you rewrite your code to a minimal working example (MWE)? Then only our knowledge can help you.

Comment: There was a question about this just the other day: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41679770/how-can-i-change-plt-plot-x-axis-from-0-to-real-value/41682755).